# Unexpected behaviour of change detection with OnPush strategy

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I've faced with very strange behaviour of change detector (with OnPush). I am not even able to explain it to myself and don't know how to fix it. Nevertheless I've reproduced this behaviour in very simple example on `stackblitz`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h28cw8

There are three components: main `app` component, `data` component and `loading indicator` component. Main component can display the `data` component through the `<router-outlet>` when user click the `Go to data` link. There is also service (aka state of the application). When user click `Go to data`, the `data` component requests this service for data, which is loaded with some delay. To emulate this delay I use rxjs timer, but with `HttpClient` the behaviour is absolutely the same. Data & loading values are binded by the use of `async` pipe. But for some reason data is displayed as expected, but `loading` isn't (it's better to say that it works from time to time, but not always). That causes the loading indicatior doesn't appear on the screen. I also log values to the console where it's easy to see that the `loading$` observable emits value, but the `@Input` binding doesn't work for some reason. Why it works so, and how to fix that?

Comment: It works for me if I move the loading component into the data component: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7ywxj. I use OnPush, but I don't use async pipes, so I'm used to calling `this.changeDetector.detectChanges()` fairly frequently. Maybe I'll start migrating to the async pipe method (providing it can work consistently with OnPush)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is not working is because you're emitting `this._loading.next(true)` value from child component after parent component has been checked.

**Async pipe does triggers subscription** and **works as intended**, that is runs `cdRef.markForCheck();`. But it **doesn't run change detection but rather only marks component, where AsyncPipe is used, to be checked**. Once a new change detection cycle starts your component will recognize input changes.

To fix it you can wrap `this._common.getData()` in microtask in your child component

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => {
   this._common.getData();
});
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slaq99?file=src/app/data/data.component.ts)**

Comment: Could you fix your link please, it can't be opened. Thanks :-)

Comment: @DonTomato Sorry, miscopied https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slaq99?file=src/app/data/data.component.ts

Comment: ok, I started to understand why my solution didn't work. But how does your solution with microtask work?

Comment: My solution works because this way we force Angular to trigger change detection from the beginning, meaning your parent component will be checked after mirtotask finishes. That's common practive used in Angular https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/81241af7ac1d320ad17feba1b69fd34f04ac278a/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L46

Comment: Another example https://github.com/angular/components/blob/321d3f92daf40a5754d97cf7f71248d37ab9e0d5/src/material-experimental/mdc-checkbox/checkbox.ts#L321

Comment: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/321d3f92daf40a5754d97cf7f71248d37ab9e0d5/src/cdk/scrolling/virtual-scroll-viewport.ts#L100 https://github.com/angular/components/blob/321d3f92daf40a5754d97cf7f71248d37ab9e0d5/src/cdk/scrolling/virtual-scroll-viewport.ts#L188

Comment: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/1ad9ef07dbe50f3774f3c5891d0d82d7eec0593c/src/material/dialog/dialog-content-directives.ts#L98 https://github.com/angular/components/blob/636ae5c8754008bfcf4b2f3953c6b2c5a7e27a1a/src/material-experimental/mdc-slide-toggle/slide-toggle.ts#L302

Comment: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/12edc0b61e01ea887697837007562307f50662f4/src/material-experimental/mdc-chips/chip-set.ts#L178 https://github.com/angular/components/blob/49a1324acc05cec1c5ff28d729abfe590f6772dd/src/material/tooltip/tooltip.ts#L216

Comment: ooook... The problem is that in the original project I have a lot of components with huge routing configuration. And I decided to use one loading indicator on the parent level for all child components. Your solution means I have to wrap almost all requests  throughout the application whenever loading indicator has to be used. just for f indicator. Doesn't look good. Of course I can manualy subscribe to the `loading$` on the parent level and trigger changeDetection manually. Is there a more elegant way? Or it is quite normal solution? Thanks in advance )

Comment: Just wrap `this._loading.next(true)` in a `Promise.resolve.then` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tykjhz?file=src/app/state/common.service.ts It doesn't matter where you're forcing rechecking root component but you have to do it if you want to see the changes there